# PHP mb_convert_encoding convert from UTF-8 to SHIFT JIS is wrong

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, shift-jis, mb-convert-encoding

I use **mb_convert_encoding** function to convert **UTF8** characters to **SJIS** characters.

Before conversion:**でんぱ組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ**

After conversion: **て?んは?組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ**

Non-convertible characters: **て?んは?**

Code used to convert :

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding('でんぱ組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ', "SJIS", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: So most likely there is no valid conversion for those characters. Which is why they have to be transcribed.

Answer (score 0):

`で` as 1 grapheme is only a rendering of composing the 2 Unicode codepoints `て` and `◌゙` (not to be confused with the codepoint `゛` that can't be combined) - the former can be translated from UTF-8 to Shift-JIS, the latter not.

Same thing with: `ぱ` - it's combined from `は` and `◌゚` instead of being one single character:

|  | [で](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A7) | て | ◌゙ | [ぱ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B1) | は | ◌゚ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unicode | U+3066 | U+3067 | U+3099 | U+3071 | U+306F | U+309A |
| [UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12352&number=128) | `e3 81 a6` | `e3 81 a6` | `e3 82 99` | `e3 81 b1` | `e3 81 af` | `e3 82 9a` |
| [Shift-JIS or CP932](https://uic.io/en/charset/show/cp932/) | `82 c5` | `82 c4` | (doesn't exist) | `82 cf` | `82 cd` | (doesn't exist) |

Just because you **see** 1 grapheme (f.e. で or ぱ) in Unicode (f.e. in UTF-8) it doesn't mean it is **build from** 1 codepoint. You can neither trust your eyes, nor your user's input - it can either be really 1 codepoint or not. You have to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) your UTF-8 text (f.e. to the [NFC form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms)) before converting it to Shift-JIS, as then those 2 codepoints (U+3067 and U+3099) for 1 grapheme also become 1 codepoint (U+3066), which can then also be translated to Shift-JIS without problems (`82 c5`).

In PHP the [extension `intl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) must be installed, then you can use [`normalizer_normalize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) - the result of that function can then be fully converted to Shift-JIS.